# FreeDNS Subdomain Hijack

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, hijack

Recently, I found out that someone add subdomain without my company permission. My primary domain using [freedns.affraid.org](http://freedns.affraid.org) service as its domain tools. I've already set that status : Invisible so does the shared status.

For illustrations:

```
Domain    : funky.net
Subdomain : me.funky.net (owned by me)
          : other.funky.net (other people)
```

How to remove subdomain other.funky.net from my subdomain list at [freedns.affraid.org](http://freedns.affraid.org) ? Do I have to become premium member of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**http://freedns.afraid.org/faq/#14**

> 1). Public - If you add your domain as
>   public, this shared queue will not be
>   used at all, others will be permitted
>   to attach to subdomains off your
>   domain without involving your
>   approval.
>
> 2). Private - If you add your domain
>   as private, then you will be able to
>   screen your domains of which you
>   decide to allow and deny. While
>   domains are in the shared queue
>   pending acceptance or not, they WILL
>   function on the global Internet. It is
>   assumed that you will support this
>   concept, and approve the majority, and
>   only deny those that you deem
>   offensive or slanderous.
>
> 3). Invisible / Stealth - If you add
>   your domain as invisible (premium
>   members only), your domain will not be
>   available for anyone else but you to
>   use, and the shared queue will not be
>   used at all. Invisible gives you
>   completely private domain hosting
>   where no one else may attach to your
>   domain. Also some domains go in
>   invisible by default if they come from
>   other free DNS providers and the like,
>   then they are not shared. If you
>   believe your domain is being
>   incorrectly marked as invisible and
>   wish to share it, contact me.

If you don't want to share your domain then you can either:

- Host your own dns
- Pay for DNS services
- Move your domain to a registrar that offers DNS for free

Your DNS isn't "hijacked", you signed up for a free service that involved sharing subdomains of your domain.

Comment: http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/3738/domain.png, as you can see at the image, my domain status already invisible and shared status also invisible. Therefore I can conclude that someone hijack my subdomain referring to number 3. Is it correct?

Comment: The FAQ answer I posted also says that you must pay for premium membership to use the invisible status.

Comment: Contact Josh, who runs Afraid (he's available via email, and very helpful) if you have any issues with an Invisible listing. Sounds like you're not paying for Invisible privileges so they'll always be shared. You can reject from your Shared Queue (from the dashboard) if you don't want them. After signing up, I quickly upgraded to a Premium package and have used their DNS hosting for many years. he's helped remove unwanted domain records. Hosting's pretty great and super reliable.